# Are there any risk if your DNS's SOA or admin contact are using the same domain as the DNS

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, domain-registrar, startup

For example, Google.com [1]

1. The SOA email is : dns-admin.google.com
2. The contact is:

   Administrative Contact:
       DNS Admin
       Google Inc.
       dns-admin.google.com

As you can see, both are using `google.com`, I am thinking it is safe to use the same domain, i.e. consider the case you lost control of the domain, you can receive email also.

(Of course Google is a public company so the chance is low, but might occur for smaller company that their domain might be stolen..)

So, do you recommend use your the same domain as the contact or others free services such as gmail?

[1] http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any significant problem with having your contact info be on the same domain as your domain name.

In fact, it might actually be more secure, as free services may have security holes that would allow an attacker to hijack your free account and steal your domain name.